# Disable e.preventDefault() if successful post validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

### Overview

Below is how is what I want to happen:

```
1. User answers the form, clicks submit
2. The data will be evaluated by the CodeIgniter `validate_new_account()`
     a. If there are errors, prevent submission so that the dynamically added fields will not disappear
     b. If successful / no error validation, proceed to the **else** part of `validate_new_account()` to `$this->view_preview_form( $this->get_post_data() );`
```

I have a form and I submit it to my controller's `validate_new_account()` function:

```
function validate_new_account() 
{
    // validations here 

    if ( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {
    // JSON-encoded validations
        $errors = json_encode( $this->form_validation->error_array() );
        echo $errors;
    } else {
        // next step
    $this->view_preview_form( $this->get_post_data() );
    }
}
```

I use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) to interact with the controller.

```
var options = {
    url: "<?php echo site_url('new_account/validate_new_account'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      if (data.length === 0) {
        alert('Form successfully submitted!');
      } else {
        // echo validation errors from CodeIgniter
        alert("Some fields weren't answered successfully. Please answer them.");
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
          var container = '<div class="error">'+value+'</div>';
          $('.form-element input[name="'+key+'"]').after(container);
        });

      }

    }
};

$('#main-submit').click(function(e) {
  $('#main-form').valid();
  $('#main-form').ajaxSubmit(options);  
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

### Problem

Without my ajax function, the code above works perfectly but I have dynamically added elements which requires ajax to handle all validations or else these elements will be gone (bad UX).

So if I enable and use my ajax function, the validation errors from CodeIgniter are printed out how I want (through the success part of the ajax) **BUT if all validations are now correct, the form does not go to `$this->view_preview_form( $this->get_post_data() );`**.

Why is this happening? I've search for similar problems but sadly none are similar to my case.

**How can I get pass through `e.preventDefault()` if the form was sent successfully?**

### Feels

To all who helped me with this problem, may it be a comment or an answer, thank you very much. I've been searching for this solution (CodeIgniter validation + jQuery validation + AJAX submission + seamless file upload) for two months and now I can finally breathe. I will never forget all of your help. You'll never know how much this means to me.

Comment: You want to submit the form if validation fails? is it what you mean?

Comment: No, I want to submit the form if the validation is right.

Comment: If you're using `AJAX`, then why want to resubmit the form?

Comment: I actually want to leave the form if the validation is successful. The controller should redirect to the preview form if the ajax validation is correct. Is that possible?

Comment: You're going to submit the form again in that case @thekalaban. It is already submitted through the ajax request...

Comment: If that's the case, how do I leave the form and continue with the flow as defined in the controller? I'm sorry, ajax is not my strength right now...

Comment: Formvalidation can be achieved entirely in HTML5 these days:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/#.USI9uqV0mBo

Comment: @cIph3r, thank you for the suggestion but my target clients use ***long sigh*** < IE9. But I'll go check that awesome update!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples:

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        // do your AJAX validation here
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var params = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, params, function(response) {
            if (response.errors.length > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will stop the form from submitting if there’s more than one error returned. Otherwise, the event will carry on as normal and propagate.

Comment: @thekalaban The above was written off-the-cuff. `params` would be the data you send to your script, usually `$(this).serialize()` to serialize the form’s inputs and send their values.

Answer (score 0):

I think after the validation you want to block the form submission, to prevent the page from being reloaded. If that's what you want then try this

Binding the handler on `submit` event of the form instead of `click` event of the button and returning `false`, which will prevent the `form` submission

```
$('#main-form').on('submit', function () {

    $(this).valid(); // do your validation here
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); // then call the ajax function

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hello, I added new details to the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not very much familiar with the codeigniter, however, you can check if the validator has returned any error. if yes, you `return false;`